# Account Validation Rule That Exempts Specific Profile IDs

Tags: formula, validation

I'm hoping to create a validation rule so that Once a Ship To ID (custom field on account) exists that starts with "6" or "7" users cannot change the Account Name with the exception of if you are a users with a system admin or a datamigration profile (profile IDs listed below).

I have created this but it is not working--

```
AND (
    LEFT (Ship_To_ID__c, 1) = "6" || LEFT (Ship_To_ID__c, 1) ="7",
    ISCHANGED ( Name ), 
    $Profile.Id <> "00eC00000012E4i"|| $Profile.Id <> "00e800000017STg"
 )
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the profile ids here, consider using a custom setting or a custom label instead.  That way, you'll be able to change the id(s) being checked for without having to change your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an OR to check the profile, which means that if it is one, it won't be the other (it will always be true). What you meant to do was to use AND, meaning it must not be one AND not be the other. You can also make the first part more efficient by using CONTAINS.

```
AND(
    CONTAINS("67", LEFT(Ship_To_ID__c,1),
    ISCHANGED(Name),
    AND($Profile.Id <> "00eC00000012E4i",$Profile.Id <> "00e800000017STg")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below will always return `true`:

```
$Profile.Id <> "00eC00000012E4i"|| $Profile.Id <> "00e800000017STg"
```

For example if the validation rule runs against a user with the Profile "00eC00000012E4i" then the above line will evaluate to `true || false` which is `true`.

You should be doing an `AND` not an `OR`

```
AND($Profile.Id <> "00eC00000012E4i", $Profile.Id <> "00e800000017STg")
```

Further more you should not be relying on Id's in your code. This will mean that you will need to update the validation rule when it is being moved to a different org which will have different Profile Ids. Consider using Profile.Name instead, eg:

```
AND($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", $Profile.Name <> "Data Migration")
```